# Conflict vs Overlap in Snorkel Label Analyzer

Tags: machine-learning, labeling

I am currently working on a weakly supervised approach to labeling training data. Snorkel helps make the process a lot easier by providing methods to facilitate labeling, modeling, etc. [Snorkel Tutorial](https://github.com/snorkel-team/snorkel-tutorials/blob/master/spam/01_spam_tutorial.ipynb)
Following along the tutorial I wrote similar labeling Functions as follows,

```
@labeling_function()
def dips_contains_fondue(x):
   return Dips if "fondue" in x.text.lower() else ABSTAIN
```

*where Dips and ABSTAIN are variables with numeric values.*

Using their **LFAnalysis** API gives a matrix with all sorts of useful information. Adding more LFs and computing over my sample data, this is the output of LFAnalysis,

[image]

I understand the following,

1. Coverage: % of samples for which at least one LF votes positive or negative
2. Polarity: tells you what values the LF returns.

But I am unable to distinguish between overlap and conflicts. More intuitively, what does it mean when they are equal, or more generally how is the calculation done?

This is the [API doc](https://snorkel.readthedocs.io/en/master/packages/_autosummary/labeling/snorkel.labeling.LFAnalysis.html#snorkel-labeling-lfanalysis), but I am afraid they don't show details on the computation.

Comment: I don't know Snorkel well, but I'd assume an overlap is where two (or more) rules came to the same conclusion and conflict is where two (or more) rules disagreed.

Answer (score 1):

- Overlap: a data point is labeled by **more than one LF**. These LFs can assign the same or different labels.
- Conflict: a data point is **labeled differently by two LFs**.

Reference: https://codeclimate.com/github/HazyResearch/snorkel/snorkel/labeling/analysis.py/source

````py
def _covered_data_points(self) -> np.ndarray:
    """Get indicator vector z where z_i = 1 if x_i is labeled by at least one LF."""
    return np.ravel(np.where(self._L_sparse.sum(axis=1) != 0, 1, 0))
 
def _overlapped_data_points(self) -> np.ndarray:
    """Get indicator vector z where z_i = 1 if x_i is labeled by more than one LF."""
    return np.where(np.ravel((self._L_sparse != 0).sum(axis=1)) > 1, 1, 0)

def _conflicted_data_points(self) -> np.ndarray:
    """Get indicator vector z where z_i = 1 if x_i is labeled differently by two LFs."""
    m = sparse.diags(np.ravel(self._L_sparse.max(axis=1).todense()))
    return np.ravel(
        np.max(m @ (self._L_sparse != 0) != self._L_sparse, axis=1)
        .astype(int)
        .todense()
    )

```
````